# S3 WebsiteRedirectionLocation meta seems aggressively browser cached

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, caching, browser-cache

I am attempting to create a URL redirection service with S3 and while the meat of the work is done, I am running into some edge case situations such as editing redirects after they are created.  I am the AWS Javascript SDK and the putObject() method to create these keys, and I have a domain mapped to the bucket - mybucket.com and is not sitting behind Cloudfront.

If I create key, foo, and set the WebsiteRedirectionLocation to something like `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property` everything works just fine. Visiting `https://mybucket.com/foo` redirects to `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property`.

However, I made a mistake and need to change the URL, so I log into the AWS console and edit the meta data for that key to change the website redirection to `https://google.com` and then once again visit `https://mybucket.com/foo`,but it *still* redirects to `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property`.  If I visit the URL in a private browser however, it correctly redirects to google which tells me the redirect is browser cached.

So it seems my browser is caching the redirect.  Now, I had set the following attributes when creating the key with the putObject method:

```
CacheControl: 'no-store',
Expires: 123456789,
```

Which is probably redundant, as `CacheControl: no-store` should tell the browser to just never cache this right?  I set the `Expires` to 123456789 which expired in 1973 so I assumed the browser would just say, well its much later than 1973 so fetch the new version.  I should also point out that I only added the `Expires` attribute after the `CacheControl` setting ha no effect.

The entire putObject call I am making looks like this:

```
  S3.putObject(
    {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: 'foo',
      CacheControl: 'no-store',
      Expires: 123456789,
      WebsiteRedirectLocation: 'https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property',
      Metadata: {
        someOtherThing: 'whatever',
      },
    }
  );
```

One thins I am seeing is that the response headers from the S3 object seem to be missing both the cache-control and expires attributes:

```
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 14:29:34 GMT
Location: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2: ldfskg;lksdjfgl;kdfjslgk;jdsflk;gjfsd
x-amz-request-id: ;fdjsglsfdkglfldsjglksf
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is the way modern browsers work. They automatically cache HTTP 301 responses. This makes certain amount of sense since the response is called `Moved Permanently`. What you need to do is return HTTP 302 which is `Moved Temporarily`

That brings us to your other problem: you're trying to use S3 `Website-Redirect-Location` meta tag for returning a `302` response. Unfortunately there's no way to do this.

I did find a workaround to accomplish this with S3: you can create a redirect rule.

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>foo</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HttpRedirectCode>302</HttpRedirectCode>
      <HostName>example.com</HostName>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

The above routing rules basically makes it so that `mybucket.com/foo` will redirect to `https://example.com` with 302 response code.

Routing rules are a feature of S3 static website hosting so you can just add this in static website hosting section of your bucket in AWS console. It's not pretty but should do the trick.

Comment: so with that method, i would need to create a routing rule for each redirect then?

Comment: unfortunately yes. Although on the bright side, since RoutingRules in an XML document, you should be able to do it fairly easy programmatically.